# How to change local state without changing global state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a blog and I want to show a list of articles under each post so the user do not need to go back to the front page. But I do not want the article they are currently reading to be in the list.
I am using filter method and it's working, but only for a split second. As far as i understand it is happening because of the useContext. I do not want to change global state, only local.

```
const ArticleDetails = (props) => {

 const {data} = useContext(ArticleContext); //data with all fetched articles from db

 const article = props.location.state.article; //data for individual article

 return (
  <div>

  //showing here data for individual post that i passed in props

    {data.filter(item => {return item !== article})
         .map(item => {return <ArticleList articleTitle={item.title} key={item.id} />})}
  </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be that the useContext hooh has been completed some modification to the data you use in return after the render.

By filter or map you actually are not changing any global state or local state at all.

After that above mentioned update, your data items might be changing. Also your filter function needs to filter with a never changing id or something like that so your filter results stays consistent across renders or state updates.

```
data.filter(item => {return item.id !== article.id})
```

Also using equality for the objects like that will not work for your filter criteria. You use not equal criteria and yes after a render your `item` will not be equal to `article` in a subsequent render even they are same reference in one render. That kind of equality is checked by `Object.is` that would be a specific need. But I think you just need an `id` check.

Comment: Then you could check it as the answer! You are welcome!